# Is 1/x the "slowest" asymptotically falling off differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics, mathematical-physics

As a physicist, I tend to think about $\sim 1/x$ as the "slowest" fall-off of a "reasonable" function. Let us state this formally:
$${\rm lim}_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0, f(x) \in Reas \implies \exists A \in \mathbb{R}:  {\rm lim}_{x \to \infty} x f(x) = A \,. $$
Where $Reas$ can be for example the set of real analytic functions $C^\omega (\mathbb{R})$.

For the case of strictly real analytic functions I have a hunch that the $0$ infinity limit could even imply quicker fall-offs, so let us think about $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ where things such as $x/(x^2+ \epsilon)$ definitely have the $1/x$ asymptotics.

So, is there a class of functions $SloFall\subset C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ for which

$$\forall f(x) \in SloFall: {\rm lim}_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0 \land {\rm lim}_{x \to \infty} |x f(x)| = \infty \,? $$

Could you give some examples of such functions? If such functions do not exist in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, would there be an example of such a function say in at most $C^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x^2+2)}$

Comment: If you are willing to consider only the domain $(0,+\infty)$, try $f(x) = \log(x)$, or $\log(\log(x))$, or ...

Comment: @MarcinMalogrosz Yes, thanks. Simple, I should have thought about this, but sometimes you are just stuck. So I guess the class is quite wide with all these regularized slower-than-x non-zero functions in the denominator.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks, you can always move the pole into the complex plane as has Marcin done, so this provides a large class of smooth  functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are innumerable examples, and you needn't use transcendentals like logarithms.  On the interval $[1,\infty]$ let $f(x)$ be the reciprocal of the square root or the cube root or ... etc.  These fall off more slowly than $1/x$ but $xf(x)$ becomes infinite. Shift the domain left if you want to incorporate values less than 1.  In a more theoretical mode, you can smoothly splice a function onto one of these at the left endpoint to demonstrate the existence of functions in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ that have the same asymptotic behavior.